# mongodb aggregate skip limit count for pagination

Tags: mongodb, pagination, mongodb-query

I want to apply the pagination on this aggregated data (all the documents which matched and project with both collection 2 and 3). I have tried multiple 
queries, i am passing limit 25 but it will get only 20 document, which changes require in this query for pagination

```
var pipeline = [{
        $match: query
    }, {
        $limit: limit
    }, {
        $skip: skip
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection2",
            localField: "collection1Field",
            foreignField: "collection2Field",
            as: "combined1"
        }
    }, {
        "$unwind": "$combined1"
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection3",
            localField: "collection1Field",
            foreignField: "collection3Field",
            as: "combined2"
        }
    }, {
        "$unwind": "$combined2"
    }, {
        $project: {
            "collection1Field1": 1,
            "collection1Field2": 1,
            "collection1Field3": 1,
            "collection2Field.field1": 1,
            "collection2Field.field2": 1,
            "collection3Field.field1": 1,
            "collection3Field.field2": 1,
        }
    }
];
```

Answer (score 9):

I just had a similar issue. I was getting no results back on "page 2" due to the fact that I ran `limit`, then `skip`.

The docs for `$skip`:

> Skips over the specified number of documents that pass into the stage
>   and passes the remaining documents to the next stage in the pipeline.

The docs for `$limit`:

> Limits the number of documents passed to the next stage in the
>   pipeline.

This means that if you run `limit` before `skip` then the results returned by the limit are then potentially truncated by the `skip`.

For example if `limit` is 50 and `skip` is 50 (for say page 2) then the match will find items, limit the results to 50, and then subsequently skip 50, thus feeding 0 results into any stages afterwards.

**I WOULD NOT RECOMMEND** running `$skip` and `$limit` at the end of the query as the DB will have done pipeline operations on a substantial amount of data that will be skipped/limited out at the end. Additionally there is a limit to the amount of memory aggregations can use which will end queries in a error if the limit is exceeded (100MB - see bottom). There is an option to turn on disk use if you exceed this limit, but a good way to optimize your code without relying on disk is to skip + limit your results before entering any `$lookup` or `$unwind` steps.

The one exception to the rule is `$sort` which is intelligent enough to use `$limit` if `$limit` immediately follows `$sort` (docs):

> When a `$sort` immediately precedes a `$limit` in the pipeline, the `$sort`
>   operation only maintains the top **n** results as it progresses, where **n**
>   is the specified limit, and MongoDB only needs to store **n** items in
>   memory. This optimization still applies when **allowDiskUse** is **true** and
>   the **n** items exceed the aggregation memory limit.

From your code I would recommend the following (skip then limit):

```
var pipeline = [{
    $match: query
}, {
    $skip: skip
}, {
    $limit: limit
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "collection2",
        localField: "collection1Field",
        foreignField: "collection2Field",
        as: "combined1"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$combined1"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "collection3",
        localField: "collection1Field",
        foreignField: "collection3Field",
        as: "combined2"
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$combined2"
}, {
    $project: {
        "collection1Field1": 1,
        "collection1Field2": 1,
        "collection1Field3": 1,
        "collection2Field.field1": 1,
        "collection2Field.field2": 1,
        "collection3Field.field1": 1,
        "collection3Field.field2": 1,
    }
}];
```

Docs regarding aggregatation pipeline limits:

> Memory Restrictions Changed in version 2.6.
>
> **Pipeline stages have a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM**. If a stage
>   exceeds this limit, MongoDB will produce an error. To allow for the
>   handling of large datasets, use the allowDiskUse option to enable
>   aggregation pipeline stages to write data to temporary files.
>
> Changed in version 3.4.
>
> The `$graphLookup` stage must stay within the 100 megabyte memory limit.
>   If `allowDiskUse: true` is specified for the `aggregate()` operation, the
>   `$graphLookup` stage ignores the option. If there are other stages in
>   the `aggregate()` operation, `allowDiskUse: true` option is in effect for
>   these other stages.

Answer (score 2):

You want to paginate after you get the results.

```
var pipeline = [{
        $match: query
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection2",
            localField: "collection1Field",
            foreignField: "collection2Field",
            as: "combined1"
        }
    }, {
        "$unwind": "$combined1"
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: "collection3",
            localField: "collection1Field",
            foreignField: "collection3Field",
            as: "combined2"
        }
    }, {
        "$unwind": "$combined2"
    }, {
        $project: {
            "collection1Field1": 1,
            "collection1Field2": 1,
            "collection1Field3": 1,
            "collection2Field.field1": 1,
            "collection2Field.field2": 1,
            "collection3Field.field1": 1,
            "collection3Field.field2": 1,
        }
    }, {
        $limit: limit
    }, {
        $skip: skip
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use some *npm modules* for pagination you can Implementing pagination very easily. for exapmle if you use `mongoose-aggregate-paginate` then you just add it into the schema like...

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongooseAggregatePaginate = require('mongoose-aggregate-
paginate');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
text: {
    type: String,
},
},
 {
    collection: 'chat',
    timestamps: true
});

chatSchema.plugin(mongooseAggregatePaginate);
const chat = mongoose.model('chat', chatSchema);
module.exports = chat;
```

After this whenever you need `pagination`, Your query should be

```
UserCtr.get = (req, res) => {

    const { limit } = 10;
    const { page } = req.query.page;

    const aggregateRules = [{
            $match: {
                _id: req.user.id
            },
            {
                //Perform your query
            }
        ];



        Chat.aggregatePaginate(aggregateRules, {
            page,
            limit
        }, (err, docs,
            pages, total) => {
            if (!err) {
                const results = {
                    docs,
                    total,
                    limit,
                    page,
                    pages,
                };
                res.status(200).json(results);
            } else {
                res.status(500).json(err);
            }
        });
    };
```

It gives response like

```
  {
  "docs": [
      {
          "_id": "5a7676c938c185142f99c4c3",
      },
      {
          "_id": "5a7676c938c185142f99c4c4",
      },
      {
          "_id": "5a7676cf38c185142f99c4c5",
      }
  ],
  "total": 3,
  "limit": 50,
  "page": "1",
  "pages": 1
}
```

Comment: Cheers, mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2 works well too